# translating kp-NUM keys

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I am migrating from GNU/Linux to Mac. I am using an MS Windows numeric keyboard (Logitech K200), and I cannot seem to map the keypad keys (`kp-N`) into anything (I had been doing that using `global-set-key` in my `.emacs`).

When I run `describe-key` and press a key I see it gets translated to the related number key, e.g. `describe-key` then press `kp-5` yields: `5 (translated from <kp-5>) runs the command Custom-no-edit...`.

Similarly for Ctrl-/Meta-/Shift-. Adding e.g. `(global-set-key <C-kp-5> 'goto-line)` to my `.emacs` does not change anything that I can see, so I assume the translation is happening before the key mapping.

How can I disable the translation of all the `kp-`*N*s so I can redfine them using `global-set-key`?

Comment: FWIW I did 4 different searches on emacs StackExhange and read through about 20 Q's & A's but got stuck trying to figure out where these keypad keys were being translated, let alone how to stop it (or change it). This was so trivial to do on linux, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was led astray by the `C-h k` output (e.g. `...(translated from <kp-5>)...`) which I took to mean that the syntax `<kp-5>` was OK for `KEY` in `global-set-key`. When I did `(global-set-key [kp-5] 'goto-line)` instead it works as I expect. Both forms had worked on the system I came from. I found this by going though my `.emacs` and testing the various `global-set-key` forms I had there. I still have the issue that `Num Lock` is not working, but since I use the keypad for mostly navigation I can live with that.

Comment: You can use `(kbd "<kp-5>")`  or `[kp-5]`     since the first expression returns the second one.

Comment: If you have not yet fixed your Num Lock issue, you may want to take a look at what I use in [PEL](https://github.com/pierre-rouleau/pel#readme) to handle that.  Look at the [pel-numkpad.el](https://github.com/pierre-rouleau/pel/blob/master/pel-numkpad.el) code and at the [Number Keypad PDF](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pierre-rouleau/pel/master/doc/pdf/numkeypad.pdf).